# Testing which of two clusters of vectors is tighter

Tags: clustering

I have two clusters of vectors. I want to test whether the vectors in the first cluster are closer to each other than those in the second are to each other.

Should I be using a distance metric (finding the average distance between each pair of vectors in a cluster) or a correlation metric (finding the average correlation between each pair of vectors in a cluster) to compare between the two clusters?

Someone on a different thread suggested a silhouette coefficient, but that method answers a slightly different question (namely, whether each vector in one cluster is better off being assigned to its own cluster or to the nearest neighboring one). I am not trying to assess the success of the clustering.

Edit: the vectors are 1280-dimensional

Comment: Do you vectors have a specific dimension?

Comment: Yes, they're 1280-dimensional